# Significado de la palabra "ora"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Cuando leo, a veces, encuentro la palabra "ora". No es difícil inferir que esta palabra se usa como "ahora". ¿Por qué se usa esta palabra? O, mejor dicho, ¿cuándo es apropiado o no usar esta palabra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se suele usar duplicada para indicar alternancia: *ora lloraba, ora reía* (de manera similar a «bien... bien» o «ya... ya»).

Es raro usarlo fuera del lenguaje poético o arcaico.

Comment: Raro, pero no por que no suela encontrarse fuera del campo de la poesía, pero raro porque esa palabra la encontré en dos libros. Primeramente en un texto universitario, el cual de poético no tiene nada, y en la novela 2666 de Bolaño, en varias ocasiones, pero, si mal no recuerdo, las instancias mas comunes en donde aparecen estas palabras es en la cuarta parte de la novela, es decir La Parte de los crímenes, que, diciéndolo con toda honestidad, no tiene nasa de poético(Salvo en ciertos pasajes), mas bien es una prosa frontal y honesta, hasta periodística, pero es que la situación la amerita.

Comment: Descriptivamente, sigo pensando que es más habitual encontrárselo en contextos líricos; pero tienes razón en que eso no responde a tu pregunta. Creo que en ese caso entramos en cómo pondera el autor que el uso de esa expresión afectaría al tono o al registro en que se mueve el pasaje que esté escribiendo. Por eliminar contextos bastante claros (y aún así seguro que encontramos excepciones), yo diría que es mejor evitarlo en registros informales... ¿Y quizás la mayoría de los orales?